# Hasura: Create Second Row When User Insert New Row

Tags: node.js, graphql, hasura

I am using Hasura on cloud with Postgresql DB.

I have a table called ***repositories*** and i would like to achieve this behavior:
When the user creates new repository (with my *insert_repositories_one* mutation) I want to create another repository (insert second row to the table) automaticlly for caching.

I am familiar with Hasura Events but it feels unnecessary to create a new API post request for the event webhook just for creating another repository based on the previos one.
Can it be done only with configuration on Hasura?
Or should I dive into Postgresql triggers and try to accomplish it there?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just want to add one more row to the table with same values ?? Can you help me understand why ? I know you said caching but how does this duplicate row help ?

Comment: It does not has the same values. When the user creates something called _remote repository_ (which gets data from remote servers) and called it for example 'usa-remote-repository', I want another repository called 'usa-remote-repository-cache' will be created behind the schene. When the user request data from the 'usa-remote-repository', the data will first be looked in the cache repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to accomplish this using Hasura alone. You could  update your mutation so that both records are created as part of a single transaction.

If you want it to happen "automatically" in response to an insert without needing to have imperative code in your mutation I would recommend that you create a Postgres Trigger instead to take care of the logic. The advantage here is that no matter how the row gets inserted (even if you do it manualy with a SQL query and circumvent the GraphQL API) you will always have a consistent data model